# MySQL column value not exist in other column on the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I want to run a mysql query to select all rows from a table "a" where the value of the ID column does not exist in ID_REFERENCE column.

Here is a my table content:

> | ID | ID_REFERENCE | TOTAL | NAME |
>   | 1 
>   |     3    
>   |   1500  |  John  |
>  | 2
>    |     -     
>   |   1000  |  Eric   |
>   | 3 
>   |     1     |  
>   1300  |  John  |
>  | 4 
>   |     8     |  
>   1000  |  Alex  |
>  | 5 
>   |     -     
>   |   2000  |  Bani |
>  | 6 
>   |     7     |  
>   1800  |  Adis  |
>  | 7 
>   |     -     
>   |     500  |  Adis  |
>   | 8 
>   |     4    
>   |     700  |  Alex  |

i need to display to this

> | ID | ID_REFERENCE | TOTAL | NAME |
>   | 1 
>   |     3    
>   |   2800  |  John  |
>  | 2
>    |     -     
>   |   1000  |  Eric   |
>   | 4 
>   |     8     |  
>   1700  |  Alex  |
>  | 5 
>   |     -     
>   |   2000  |  Bani |
>  | 6 
>   |     7     |  
>   2300  |  Adis  |

**ID** column is unique

i've had trouble getting the hoped. Thanks

Comment: I can see you really put efforts in the formatting, so I gave you an upvote. However, please try to learn some `markdown` syntax and use it next time, also the buttons on the editor will help you a lot.

Comment: Please use Ascii table format for formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use not exists

```
 select t1.* from a t1 where
 not exists ( select 1 from a t2 where t2. ID_REFERENCE =t1.id)
```

or use not in

```
 select t1.* from a t1 where a.ID not in ( select  ID_REFERENCE  from a where a. ID_REFERENCE  is not null)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
select min(id), max(ID_REFERENCE), sum(TOTAL),name
    from tablename
    group by name
```